# Fade in on scroll not working with classList

Tags: javascript, scrollview

I am trying to make a fade in effect on when the scroll reaches a certain point of the window.

For some reason the class `show` is not appearing whne that point is reached.

```js
const fade = document.querySelectorAll("fadeIn");

window.addEventListener("scoll", scrollFade);

scrollFade()

function scrollFade() {
  const triggerFades = window.innerHeight / 4 * 4;
  console.log(triggerFades)

  fade.forEach(fades => {
    const Fadepos = fade.getBoundingClientRect().top

    if (Fadepos < triggerFades) {
      fade.classList.add("show");
    } else {
      fade.classList.remove("show");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.fadeIn {
  animation: fadetop 3s 1 both;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadetop {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0px, 100px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  5100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col fadeIn" id="IT">
          <img src="/images/PeopleImages.com-ID2554265.jpg" alt="">

          <div class="banner animated">
            <img src="/images/left_arrow_icon.png" alt="">
            <h4>IT Solutions</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col fadeIn" id="cctv-camera">
          hello

          <div class="banner" id="cctv">
            <img src="/images/right_arrow_icon.png" id ="right-arrow" alt="">
            <h4>CCTV Monitoring</h4>
          </div>
   
        </div>
      

      <div class="col fadeIn" id="server">
        <img src="/images/AdobeStock_90603827-scaled.jpeg" alt="">

        <div class="banner" id="database">
          <img src="/images/left_arrow_icon.png" alt="">
          <h4>Client Database Management</h4>
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="col fadeIn" id="control-room">
        <img src="/images/cctv-camera-traffic-security-room.jpg" alt="">

      </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The snippet I made from the code in your question appears to work absolutely fine. Can you edit the question to include more detail, or additional code which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Well the issue is,is that the images, I have are not fading in as they are supposed to, I see the code is working, on here. for some reason the class show is not adding to the ``const fade``` in the HTML element

Comment: Please provide a [mre] then.